# "Process terminated with status -1073741510 (0 minute(s), 6 second(s))"

Tags: c

First `printf` is working, but I got that problem in the function:

```
"Process terminated with status -1073741510 (0 minute(s), 6 second(s))"
```

I just have a number of digits and want to calculate the number of pages that can be numbered with that number

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "book.h"

int main()
{
    long no_pages, no_digits;

    srand(time(0));
    no_digits=(rand()% 10000000)+10000;
    printf("The number of digits are %ld", no_digits);

    no_pages = no_of_pages(no_digits);
    printf ("\n The number of pages are %ld", no_pages);
}
```

This is the function that calculates number of pages

```
int no_of_pages(long no_digits)
{

    long no_pages=0,no_digits_page;

    while(no_digits>0)
    {
        no_pages++; // count number of pages
        long  aux=no_pages;
        long no_digits_pages=0; // conut how many digits are on a page

        while(aux)
        {
            aux=aux/10;
            no_digits_page++;
        }
        if(no_digits_page == 1)
            no_digits--;
        else
            if(no_digits_page == 2)
                no_digits=no_digits-2;
        else
            if(no_digits_page == 3)
                no_digits=no_digits-3;
        else
            if(no_digits_page == 4)
                no_digits=no_digits-4;
        else
            if(no_digits_pages == 5)
                no_digits=no_digits-5;
        else
            if(no_digits_page == 6)
                no_digits=no_digits-6;
        else
            if(no_digits_page == 7)
                no_digits=no_digits-7;
        else
            if(no_digits_page == 8)
                no_digits=no_digits-8;
        else
            if(no_digits_page == 9)
                no_digits=no_digits-9;

    }
    if (no_digits<0)
    {
        return no_pages-1;
    }
    else
        return no_pages;
}
```

Comment: Where is `no_of_pages` defined?  The problem is probably there.

Comment: Please don’t put code in comments. Edit the post and provide a [mcve] that shows the issue

Comment: ***Use a Debugger***  Step through your code one instruction at a time.

Comment: "It is too long to post here": without having some [MCVE], we can't guess even what is the problem. You may have some problem in `no_of_pages()` function, but if you don't show a *small* piece of code reproducing the same problem, we won't be able to help. 
See also [ask].

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm new here, i edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `no_of_page`

- the variable `no_digits_page` is not initialized, the behavior is undefined
- there are a lot of possibilities where you do not modify `no_digit` and loop without end

Note also the function can be easily simplified replacing

> ```
>  if(no_digits_page == 1)
>        no_digits--;
>    else
>       if(no_digits_page == 2)
>            no_digits=no_digits-2;
>    else
>        if(no_digits_page == 3)
>            no_digits=no_digits-3;
>    else
>        if(no_digits_page == 4)
>            no_digits=no_digits-4;
>    else
>        if(no_digits_pages == 5)
>            no_digits=no_digits-5;
>    else
>        if(no_digits_page == 6)
>            no_digits=no_digits-6;
>    else
>        if(no_digits_page == 7)
>            no_digits=no_digits-7;
>    else
>        if(no_digits_page == 8)
>            no_digits=no_digits-8;
>    else
>        if(no_digits_page == 9)
>            no_digits=no_digits-9;
> ```

by

```
    if ((no_digits_page >= 1) && (no_digits_page <= 9))
       no_digits -= no_digits_page;
```

Probably you confuse `no_digits_page` and `no_digits_pages`, if I remove one of them also using my simplified version :

```
int main()
{
  long no_pages, no_digits;

  srand(time(0));
  no_digits=(rand()% 10000000)+10000;
  printf("The number of digits are %ld", no_digits);

  no_pages = no_of_pages(no_digits);
  printf ("\n The number of pages are %ld\n", no_pages);
}

int no_of_pages(long no_digits)
{
  long no_pages=0;

  while(no_digits>0)
  {
    no_pages++; // count number of pages
    long  aux=no_pages;
    long no_digits_page=0; // conut how many digits are on a page

    while(aux)
    {
      aux=aux/10;
      no_digits_page++;
    }
    if ((no_digits_page >= 1) && (no_digits_page <= 9))
      no_digits -= no_digits_page;

  }
  if (no_digits<0)
  {
    return no_pages-1;
  }
  else
    return no_pages;
}
```

Compilation and execution (declaring `no_of_pages` in *book.h*) :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra -Wall a.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
The number of digits are 2211616
 The number of pages are 387120
```

The program finishes, but don't know if it computes the expected result

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to come from the `while(no_digits>0)` loop.

Indeed, you only handle when `no_digits_page` is in 1..9 range.

One simple correction could be:

```
int no_of_pages(long no_digits)
{
    long no_pages=0,no_digits_page;

    while(no_digits>0)
    {
        no_pages++; // count number of pages
        long  aux=no_pages;
        long no_digits_pages=0; // count how many digits are on a page

        while(aux)
        {
            aux=aux/10;
            no_digits_page++;
        }

        /**
         * CORRECTION'S HERE
         * instead of using a complicated if / else for each case, simplify with: 
         */
        no_digits = no_digits - no_digits_page ;

    }

    if (no_digits<0)
    {
        return no_pages-1;
    }
    else
        return no_pages;
}
```

---

That said, I'm not sure this piece of code will address your entire problem.

```
* What is the code supposed to do?
* What is the problem you want to solve?
```